# Firebase, Finding out how to find a child using queries and looking through its child's value? App authentication

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase Real Time database. I am trying to find a child using a query, then once found, I want to see if inside the child, there is a particular key with a value. I am trying to make an authentication process. I am looking if the username and password are correct. It is NOT a: Key:"username", value: "password" situation but a :

child: "username"

|

-> Key: Password, Value: "password"

Trying to find a child with a query, and within its children see if the Password key and Value exist. I know there are many similar questions about this(been looking at them for 2 hours) but none are suited my situation.

Database:

```
->admin
     -> Teacher
            -> Password: "teacherPassword"

-> Period 1
      -> Students
             -> Will Smith
                    -> Current Novel: "Fly"
                    -> Password: "password5"

-> Period 2
*Same as Period 1, different students*

-> Period 3
*Same as Period 1 , different students*
```

I have tried:

```
func CheckUser(Username: String, Password: String, completionHandler: @escaping ((_ correct : Bool)) -> Void)) {


     self.ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "\(Username)/Password").queryEqual(tovalue: "\(Password)").observe(.value) { (snapshot)  in 

         if snapshot.exists(){
             print("Found")
             completionHandler(true)      
         }else{
             print("Not found")
             completionHandler(false)  
         }

     }

}
```

I am trying to search the full database for the Username(which is Will Smith), and since all children of students have a key of Password, I added it to the query(".queryOrdered(byChild: "(Username)/Password")"). Then I see if there is a value equal to Password(which is password5). That is my reasoning but I am new to firebase so I don't really know. The console always prints out "Not Found". The solution is a combination of queries but I need help to find that solution. I do not want to use Firebase's built-in authentication.

Thanks for any help given.

Comment: Please make sure your code contains no external dependencies. So show how you initialize `self.ref`, or better yet: just reproduce the problem with a member field and only local variables. Also: please replace the schematic database structure with the actual JSON (as text, no screenshots please). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Also be aware that your description very much reads like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Instead of describing the flow of your code in text (which isn't needed, since the code already shows us what it does), describe in a few short sentences what this code is trying to accomplish.